# Jquery slider not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have two slider in my page

In separate page both are working properly,but when i put both in one page either one is not working.

**1st slider**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
```

**2nd slider**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>
```

i tried  to use `mootools-1.2.1-core.js` higher version but still also not working.
Please help me.

Comment: probably script's are getting clashed..

Comment: how can i solve this problem?

Comment: try some other alternative or try to modify the scripts if you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jquery [no-conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use `$j` instead of `$` in your jquery code.

There are always chances of conflict between these javascript libraries. I always use jquery no-conflict for all my magento website as magento uses scriptaculous as its default library. So, its good to use no-conflict if you are using jquery & some other js libraries together.