# Two slide show in single website not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am having 2 jquery slides in my website.
one is `easyslider` i am using `easyslider1.7.js` and for another slide, `mootools-1.2.1-core.js`

my jquery attachments:

```
<!-- slide1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>

<!--slide 2-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>
```

If i am disabling the `jquery.js` then 2nd slide wil work but 1st wont work. 
If i am disabling `mootools-1.2.1-core.js` the 1st wil; work properly.

How to fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have to use two slides for?

Comment: Because i need 2 slides in different ways. example : [http://www.forever21.com/Product/Main.aspx?br=f21](http://www.forever21.com/Product/Main.aspx?br=f21)

Comment: can you show us two different slides? jQuery cycle might help to have different slides with different effect.

Comment: This might be helpful http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html

Comment: I wonder how [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682792/jquery-slider-not-working) was same before this

Comment: when u use more than jquery slider it may create conflict between them, to solve your problem use jquey's noConflict() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked out for you.

You can use jQuery cycle plugin for slider and carousel.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCEtL/)

For more info please see jQuery [cycle plugin page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)